# Testing window.postMessage directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, jasmine

I'm having trouble testing my directive which enables cross-document messaging by registering a message handler:

```
.directive('messaging', function ($window, MyService) {
    return {
        link: function () {
            angular.element($window).on('message', MyService.handleMessage);
        }
    };
})
```

All I want to unit test is that when this directive is compiled, and `window.postMessage('message','*')` is called, my message handler should be called:

http://jsfiddle.net/mhu23/L27wqn14/ (including jasmine test)

I'd appreciate your help!
Michael

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your are using original `window` API, you are not mocking it, so the method `postMessage` will keep it's asynchronous behavior. Knowing that, tests should be written in an asynchronous way. In JSFiddle you have Jasmine 1.3, so test should look kinda like this:

```
it('should ....', function () {

    var done = false;

    spyOn(MyService,'handleMessage').andCallFake(function () {
        // set the flag, let Jasmine know when callback was called
        done = true; 
    });

    runs(function () {
        // trigger async call
        $window.postMessage('message','*');    
    });

    waitsFor(function () {
        // Jasmine waits until done becomes true i.e. when callback be called
        return done; 
    });

    runs(function () {
        expect(MyService.handleMessage).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });

});
```

Check the [docs about testing async with Jasmine 1.3](http://jasmine.github.io/1.3/introduction.html#section-Asynchronous_Support). And here is a [working JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hLgfetvn/2/).

It would be a bit easier in [Jasmine 2.x](http://jasmine.github.io/edge/introduction.html#section-Asynchronous_Support):

```
it('should ....', function (done) {

    spyOn(MyService,'handleMessage').and.callFake(function () {
      expect(MyService.handleMessage).toHaveBeenCalled();
      done();
    });

    $window.postMessage('message','*');
});
```

Also, I have to mention, that you have to change how you add a listener from this

```
angular.element($window).on('message', MyService.handleMessage);
```

to that

```
angular.element($window).on('message', function (e) {
    MyService.handleMessage(e);
});
```

because `.on` registers a function itself, it won't be used as a method attached to the `MyService`, so you won't be able to spy on it.

Comment: Perfect answer Michael, thanks!

Here's the Jasmine 2.0 fiddle if someone is interested: http://jsfiddle.net/mhu23/L27wqn14/